# How to correctly add SPF record

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, txt-record, sendgrid

I need to add a SendGrid SPF record for my GoDaddy domain, but I'm not sure exactly where to put it. I have an existing TXT record for @ with value of google-site-verification=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. So should I add the SPF information to that, or create a new TXT record? If I need to add it how should I do so - append it after a semicolon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a new TXT record with the spf information in there. If you want an example, we had to do the same at work:

```
$ dig -t txt booking.com
booking.com.        900 IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx/25 ip4:154.54.96.0/28 include:priceline.com include:sendgrid.net ?all"
booking.com.        900 IN  TXT "google-site-verification=RUz0C9k4tXs5skeRZsP5FGjiyGXptvWtg7YPC49bMQI"
```

Comment: `?all`? Do I even want to know?

Comment: No, I don't think you want to know `-all` would be better, but we have our reasons.

Comment: Having multiple TXT records can leads you to error. You should combine them in one : https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483

Comment: and https://www.steveroot.co.uk/2012/06/27/spf-with-google/